# Using react-native-camera, how to access saved pictures?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

My goal is to use the react-native-camera and simply show a picture on the same screen, if a picture has been taken. I'm trying to save the picture source as "imageURI". If it exists, I want to show it, if a picture hasn't been taken yet, just show text saying No Image Yet. I've got the camera working, since I can trace the app is saving pictures to the disk. Having trouble with the following:

- How to assign the capture functions data to a variable when I take the picture, that I can call later (imageURI).
- Don't know how to do an if statement in Javascript to check if a variable exists yet.

  ```
  import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

  export default class camerahere extends Component {

  _takePicture () {
    this.camera.capture((err, data) => {
    if (err) return;
    imageURI = data;
    });
  }

  render() {

    if ( typeof imageURI == undefined) {
      image = <Text> No Image Yet </Text> 
    } else {
      image = <Image source={{uri: imageURI, isStatic:true}} 
      style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
    }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera
        captureTarget={Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk}
        ref={(cam) => {
          this.camera = cam;
        }}
        style={styles.preview}
        aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>

        {button}
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._takePicture.bind(this)}>
        <View style={{height:50,width:50,backgroundColor:"pink"}}></View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  </Camera>
  ```

Answer (score 14):

I found the answer to my own question. This is an example of the react-native-camera being used.
https://github.com/spencercarli/react-native-snapchat-clone/blob/master/app/routes/Camera.js

Found this answer in another earlier posted question answered by @vinayr. Thanks! 
[Get recently clicked image from camera on image view in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583159/get-recently-clicked-image-from-camera-on-image-view-in-react-native)

Here's the code from the first link:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width
  },
  capture: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 35,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: '#FFF',
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  cancel: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 20,
    top: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: '#FFF',
    fontWeight: '600',
    fontSize: 17,
  }
});

class CameraRoute extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      path: null,
    };
  }

  takePicture() {
    this.camera.capture()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ path: data.path })
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  renderCamera() {
    return (
      <Camera
        ref={(cam) => {
          this.camera = cam;
        }}
        style={styles.preview}
        aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
        captureTarget={Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk}
      >
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.capture}
          onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}
          underlayColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
        >
          <View />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </Camera>
    );
  }

  renderImage() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: this.state.path }}
          style={styles.preview}
        />
        <Text
          style={styles.cancel}
          onPress={() => this.setState({ path: null })}
        >Cancel
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.path ? this.renderImage() : this.renderCamera()}
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export default CameraRoute;
```

Comment: @Arsalan .. hi, i think this answer has been obsolete. Do you have an update for it ?